# Creating a measure on an uncountable chain

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory

Consider a universe $\mathcal{F}$ of cardinality $|\mathcal{F}| = |\mathbb{R}|$. Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a an uncountable family of subsets of $\mathcal{F}$, which is totally ordered under the $\subseteq$ relation (namely, $|\mathcal{C}| > \aleph_0$ and for any $A,B \in \mathcal{C}$, either $A \subseteq B$ or $B \subseteq A$). In other words, $\mathcal{C}$ is a chain.

We would like to create a probability measure over $\mathcal{F}$, with the following properties:

1. Each $A \in \mathcal{C}$ is measurable.
2. Each singleton has a measure of 0.

Is it possible to create such a measure in general?

Comment: If $|\mathcal F|=|\mathbb R|$ is a [real-valued measurable cardinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurable_cardinal#Real-valued_measurable), then there is a probability measure over $\mathcal F$ such that each $A\subseteq\mathcal F$ is measurable, and each singleton has measure $0.$